# PHP request as array?

Tags: php

Im trying to load content via request and include pages, problem is that even if I put localhost/?login or ?logout , it doesn't work, shows that there is no request with name $k and priting $container .= twice (??). I never had a problems with array but I didn't try it as a website request.

```
$actions = array(
    "login" => "source/login.php",
    "logout" => "source/logout.php"
);
foreach($actions as $k => $v){
    if (!empty($_REQUEST[$k])) {
        include($v);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        $container .= "?";
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Start by debugging what you _do_ have:  `print_r($_REQUEST)` to get a sense of what keys/values are present.

Comment: try `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see what you actually have to work with. If you're just sending a single parameter (`?login`) then I suspect it won't be in $_REQUEST, and you should be looking at `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That your punishment for using `empty`. :-) Lots of values are considered `empty` by PHP.

Since `login` is just a key, but you didn't specify a value, it is considered 'empty' even though it exists in the array.

Use `array_key_exists` for a stricter check.

```
foreach($actions as $k => $v){
    if (array_key_exists($k, $_REQUEST)) {
        include($v);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        $container .= "?";
    }
}
```

Many people use `isset` for this, which is slightly better than `empty`, but I prefer `array_key_exists` since it does exactly what you expect it to do and nothing else.

The following things are considered to be empty according to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

So you can see why `empty` can give you a lot of false positives when testing for it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

another way you could do it was have your links be setup like this:

foo.com/bar.php?action=login

then have your php code do

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action == "" || array_key_exists($action,$actions) )
{
  //set to default value...
}

include($actions[$action]);
```

would this achieve your goal?